NTFS-disk don't work on Ubuntu 24:04
When I put in the disk Ubuntu cannot mount 1TB-NTFS-USB-disk. It worked a month ago and work with no problem on Windows10. Tested with 3 Ubuntu computer, and one with dual booth. Ubuntu say: Wrong superblock, no pager or something or that you need a helper program.
I have another NTFS disk with 500GB and it work fine, but that disk have I formated in Ubuntu as NTFS
/Cheers

How are you trying to mount the disk? Update your original question with the exact command you are using or the disk details from /etc/fstab. Also run tail -f /var/log/syslog and/or sudo dmesg -w in a terminal and then attempt the mount to see what log/kernel messages are shown. Update your original question with any details.

This question is similar to: Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks. USB-drives are not in fstab, I think, it mounted Will try it next time my friend with the disk return. Don't have the disk now. I just mount it by klicking the disksymbol in nautilus, as you used to do with usb-diskl. Just wonder if there have being any change in FUSE or ntfs-3g. Willl try next time he visit.

If partition mounted with Windows, it may be that Windows fast startup was on, which sets hibernation flag, preventing the Linux NTFS driver from fully mounting the partition. You may be able to manually mount read only, but need to turn off fast startup in Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

I think it is mounted with pmount, as media-disk and usb-disk use to mount now-days.

I'd say: Make sure to Eject media and shutdown Windows before using media that has been there, most importantly => do not hibernate / put to sleep.

Is there data that you would like to keep that is on the disk?  If so I would back your files up first using your Windows 10 to either another drive (usb thumb drive, cloud, or external hard drive).
After that I would use an Ubuntu live USB stick to format the disk (this destroys any data left on the disk) with gparted (install it by typing on your terminal:
sudo su
hit enter and then:
apt install gparted
What are you going to do with the disk?  Use it with Windows or Linux?  Will you use it as storage only, or are you going to install an operating system on it?
If you are going to install linux on it or use it as storage in conjuction with a linux operating system, just format it using gparted to Ext4.
If you are going to use it to install windows or as storage for a windows computer, use gparted to format it to NTFS.
Maybe it's also good to ask oneself, "Do I prefer being a user of my computer while using Windows 10 or 11, or do I prefer to be the owner of my computer while running Linux?"

I just want to se if there have being any change in ntfs-3g och fuse or something. My friend have now left with the disk (transfer files in w10).
